# Take events only after an Observable from a chain has emitted one

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming

Here is the chain: `observableOne.flatMap(event -> observableTwo).subscribe()`

I'd like to take events from `observableOne` the very first time it emits one, then ignore all other events from this `Observable` until after  `observableTwo` has either emitted a value, completed or finished with an error. Worth mentioning that ultimately I'm interested in the events from the second Observable.

The context is like, there is a `Button` clicking on which an event is fired, this is `ObservableOne`. The fired event triggers `ObservableTwo`, let's say it's a chain of network operations. So I want to ignore all button clicks while network operations are being executed.

Comment: It's usual to ignore previous network operations if the button is clicked multiple times - only taking the results of the network operation for the last button click. Why have you chosen to ignore button clicks until the current network operation is complete?

Comment: You seem to be over complicating the problem. Why not disable your button after a click has been received and re-enable it after dealing with the results of the network operation?

Comment: It's just a part of a more complicated logic, there's a reason for it

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `Flowable` instead of `Observable`, then you could use the backpressure to achieve the desired effect (drop events until `observableTwo` terminates) by setting the `maxConcurrency` of `flatMap` to `1`:

```
observableOne
    .toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.DROP)
    .flatMap(event -> observableTwo.toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.ERROR), 1)
    .subscribe();
```

I posted a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52966919/1916449).

Turns out there's also an `ObservableTransformer` exactly for this purpose in [RxJava2Extensions](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions#observabletransformersflatmapdrop) library by akarnokd. It can be used like this:

```
observableOne
    .compose(ObservableTransformers.flatMapDrop(event -> observableTwo))
    .subscribe();
```

Answer (score 0):

To control the request amounts made by `flatMap` use a special overload:

```
observableOne
  .doOnRequest(System.out::println)
  .flatMap(event -> observableTwo, 1)
  .flatMap(event -> observableThree, 1)
.subscribe()
```

If your sources `observableOne`, `observableTwo`, `observableThree` are synchronous this should not be necessary but for asynchronous sources this should do the job.

Comment: I've updated the description as it wasn't that clear.

Answer (score 0):

[Edit2] the question changed so I adapt my answer + actually give a correct answer

I don't see other way of doing this than with a status flag:

```
AtomicBoolean progress = new AtomicBoolean();
observableOne
        .filter(event -> !progress.get())
        .flatMap(event ->
                observableTwo
                        .doOnSubscribe(() -> progress.set(true))
                        .doOnTerminate(() -> progress.set(false))
        )
        .subscribe();
```

If an error happens your subscription will be canceled and you will not receive any more event, even if the button is clicked again.

If this is not what you want you can:

- resubscribe on the error callback

  ```
  private void bindRemoteCalls() {
      if (mySubscription != null) mySubscription.unsubscribe();
      AtomicBoolean progress = new AtomicBoolean();
      mySubscription = observableOne
          .filter(event -> !progress.get())
          .flatMap(event ->
                  observableTwo
                          .doOnSubscribe(() -> progress.set(true))
                          .doOnTerminate(() -> progress.set(false))
          )
          .flatMap(event -> observableTwo, 1)
          .subscribe(
              data -> handleResponse(data),
              error -> {
                  handleError(error);
                  bindRemoteCalls();
              }
          );
  }
  ```
- use `onErrorReturn()` (combine with a `doOnError()` to actually do something about it)

  ```
  AtomicBoolean progress = new AtomicBoolean();
  observableOne
      .filter(event -> !progress.get())
      .flatMap(event ->
              observableTwo
                      .doOnSubscribe(() -> progress.set(true))
                      .doOnTerminate(() -> progress.set(false))
                      .doOnError(error -> handleError(error))
                      .onErrorReturn(null)
                      .filter(data -> data != null)
      )
      .subscribe(data -> handleResponse(data));
  ```

Remember using `subscribeOn()` / `observeOn()` with the right schedulers if you need to.

Please consider using `switchMap()` in place of `flatMap()` --> if the button is pressed again the previous call is canceled (unsubscribed) and then a new one is started. Or to say it in Rx terms: the observableTwo previous subscription is unsubscribed and a new subscription is formed.

if you disable your button on unsubscribe and enable it on termination you can easily obtain the same result by making the button unclickable.

Comment: I've updated the description as it was clumsy indeed.

Comment: Sorry, i've updated my answer but it's still incorrect the additional number doesn't work as I would expect :-( it just delay the mapping

Comment: Now it's correct but need a state flag which means is not 100% reactive :)