# Flowable concatMapSingle without prefetch to ignore clicks until processing finishes

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2

I want to handle clicks in such a way that they are ignored as long as I'm doing processing of some click that occurred.

I thought I could do it by utilizing the backpressure, like this:

```
private val clicks = PublishProcessor.create<Unit>()

// ...

clicks
    .onBackpressureDrop()
    .concatMapSingle(::handleClick, 0)
```

But this throws an error, because there's a requirement that `concatMapSingle` needs to prefetch at least one item, which makes it queue the click and process it immediately after I'm done processing, which is not what I want. I want to process the click only if there is no processing happening at the moment.

Is there some other operator I could use to achieve the desired effect?

Comment: why not simply disable the button before you start processing the click?

Comment: There's no disabled state in the UI, so the user wouldn't notice any difference. Also, I never said it was a button ;)

Comment: any other clickable then. If there is no disabled state, there is no difference between disabling the clicks and ignoring them, is there?

Comment: I think there could be a race condition when disabling clicks in UI, that is not there when ignoring clicks. Also, why involve the view (adding extra method to MVP contract), if I can handle it in the presenter this easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `flatMapSingle` instead of `concatMapSingle` does the trick, [as suggested by akarnokd on GitHub](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/5720#issuecomment-343730836):

> `flatMap` will only fetch the next upstream item if the current one actually completed

The last parameter is `maxConcurrency`, specifying the maximum number of active subscriptions to the `SingleSource`s:

```
clicks
    .onBackpressureDrop()
    .flatMapSingle(::handleClick, false, 1)
```

In this instance, `flatMapSingle` subscribes to those `Single`s sequentially, so it doesn't change the semantics I got from `concatMapSingle`.